# Read csv multi column & export it

Tags: c#, csv

my csv data is something looks like this:

```
Device data for period 30/08/2016 to 30/08/2016
Site ID,Time,INC1_MD
VSI-18,2016-08-30 00:00:00,165.954
VSI-18,2016-08-30 00:01:00,14.524
VSI-18,2016-08-30 00:02:00,32.920
VSI-18,2016-08-30 00:03:00,48.508
VSI-18,2016-08-30 00:04:00,62.418
```

.....

and I try to ignore first two line and start at "VSI-18..."
and extract third column data which is after the date & time column
and export them into new csv file, 1 column per day
like:

```
day1,day2,day3
100,200,300
200,123,123
123,222,444
....
```

and here is my code

```
        o_csv_loc.Text = varFile; //csv data file location
        save_file_loc.Text = saveloc; //new csv file location

        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(varFile));
        List <string[]> listA = new List<string[]>();
        List<string[]> listB = new List<string[]>();
        List<string[]> listC = new List<string[]>();

        //I think these two code below is to skip first 2 line of csv data                
        //file and start read the third line (VSI-18...)
        reader.ReadLine();
        reader.ReadLine();

        while (reader.Peek() > -1)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(';');

            listA.Add(new string[] { values[0] });
            listB.Add(new string[] { values[1] });
            listC.Add(new string[] { values[2] });
            //I think that listC is suppose to extract the data after the 
            //second comma which is third column
        }
```

for the export data code I not yet finish because I can't figure out how to read data yet.
when debug, 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'  show on line

```
   listB.Add(new string[] { values[1] });
```

Isn't should not be problem on this line? values[0] is not problem yet.

**EDIT**

I success to export data to new csv file

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(varFile));
        List <string[]> listA = new List<string[]>(); //here are the code 
        //changed

        List<string[]> listB = new List<string[]>();
        List<string[]> listC = new List<string[]>();
        reader.ReadLine();
        reader.ReadLine();

        while (reader.Peek() > -1)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');

            listA.Add(new string[] { values[0] });
            listB.Add(new string[] { values[1] });
            listC.Add(new string[] { values[2]});

        }

        using (System.IO.TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(saveloc))
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < listC.Count; index++)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", listC[index]) + ',');
            }
        }
```

result is this:

```
165.954,
14.524,
32.920,
48.508,
62.418,
79.151,
96.982,
```

I still figuring how to detect new date and put into new column

Comment: You're splitting on `;`. I don't see any of those in your file.

Comment: Don't wrap non HTML/JS/CSS code in snippet markup. It's enough to indent it by four spaces (or highlight it and click the `{}` button).

Comment: As @Blorgbeard mentioned, I think you want to split on ',' instead of ';'

Comment: Beware custom CSV parsers. It's a more nuanced format than it first appears to be.

Comment: I'm very sorry about my so small mistake on my code, is my bad, now is ok with that read code, now just need to export the data to a new csv.

Answer (score 0):

First, like one of the comments stated...in your code you're using `;` as the delimiter character however the csv file is using `,`...so the result of `var values = line.Split(';');` is an aray with only one element.

Second, I would safeguard my application against incorrect formats or corrupted data. For example

```
var line = reader.ReadLine();

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty())//<--empty row
    continue;//<--ignore, or else add empty values to your in-memory lists

var values = line.Split(',');

listA.Add(new string[] { values.length > 0 ? values[0] : string.Empty });
listB.Add(new string[] { values.length > 1 ? values[1] : string.Empty });
listC.Add(new string[] { values.length > 2 ? values[2] : string.Empty });

//or simply

if(values.length < 3)
    continue;//<--ignore, or else add empty values to your in-memory lists
```

Answer (score 0):

Few points.

You might be getting an error/exception due to delimiter (`;`) used doesn't actually split the string, so `values[1]` throws `IndexOutOfRange` exception . Use the correct delimiters (`,` what you need).

If your intention is to generate new `csv` (with same string) why do you need to split the string? can't we directly write it to file (assuming it is `,` delimited)?

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
while (reader.Peek() > -1)
{
     var line = reader.ReadLine();
     sb.AppendLine(line);
}

// Write to file.
File.WriteAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
```

Comment: I means, I want to read the csv data file (which I have a downloader to auto download a new csv file), and I want to put it into new column per day. As you can see, the example data is on 30 August, and the only data I want is after the second comma. 
I want to extract that data into new csv file.
when start a new day, it will export a new day data beside the yesterday data, like this: day1's data, day2's data,day3's data

Comment: That's what I really mean, take the substring of what is needed (until first comma) form downloaded csv file and then append any new column if you want and then write to new file.

Comment: I know what you means but my data is like this (the comment cause you misunderstand, maybe?) 
[see here for details](http://pastebin.com/vP9r9Yzm)
Day1 data will and need to be finish collected first before Day2 data comes in. I can't wait for whole month data collected and write using .append it will write all the day1 data first, and when day2 comes, it write day2 data on new column